# Converter posições de string para inteiro

Tags: c#, .net, string, conversão-de-tipo

```
    Console.Write("Digite um numero de 4 digitos: ");
    string numero = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
    int soma = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < numero.Length; i++)
    {
        soma += Convert.ToInt32(numero[i]);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Soma dos numeros = "+soma);
```

Eu sei que seu colocar para converter o numero todo (`Convert.ToInt32(numero)`) converte normalmente, mas quando é pra converter só as posições, o programa converte a `string` para código HTML, segundo a tabela do Unicode, tipo, `2 = 50, 3 = 51`, tudo errado. Como faço para converter cada valor da `string` para `int`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uma `string` é um `array` de `char`. Então quando você acessa o `numero[i]` você está acessando um valor do tipo `char`.

[Leia sobre char](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/char), que nada mais é do que um valor numérico de 16 bits que representa um caractere. Para entender melhor sobre qual valor representa cada caracter, estude a [tabela ASCII](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII).

Para chegar no resultado que você espera, transforme seu char em string, assim:

```
soma += Convert.ToInt32(numero[i].ToString());
```

Comment: obrigado...eu já consegui o que eu queria. Era isso mesmo, uma string é um array de char, por isso que eu não estava sabendo como fazer. Quando eu colocava Convert.ToInt32(numero[0]), eu estava apenas representando o char na forma de inteiro, (na verdade o char é um numero né) daí dava o numero correspondente a tabela ASCII. Eu fiz o seguinte. Eu coloquei soma+= (int)(numero[i] - '0') e deu certo. o cahr '0' = 48 na tabela, 1 = 49, 2 = 50.... é só subtrair o '0' e já era, vlw pela resposta.

Comment: Que bom que ajudou @pauloestevão, se achar que essa resposta é a mais adequada pro seu problema você pode marca-la como aceita. :)

Answer (score 2):

As respostas já postadas quebram a aplicação quando um valor que não é um número é digitado, o correto é fazer isto:

```
using static System.Console;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        Write("Digite um numero de 4 digitos: ");
        var numero = ReadLine();
        var soma = 0;
        foreach (var chr in numero) {
            if (!char.IsDigit(chr)) {
                WriteLine("não é um número válido");
                return;
            }
            soma += chr - '0';
        }
        WriteLine($"Soma dos numeros = {soma}");
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/QpXrkE). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/kML6SB). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conversion/CharToInt.cs).

Answer (score 0):

Utilizando Linq e Generic você consegue isso de uma forma simples:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace valor_posicao_string {
    class Program {
        static void Main (string[] args) {
            Console.Write ("Digite um numero de 4 digitos: ");
            string numero = Console.ReadLine ();
            IEnumerable<int> digits = numero.Select (x => int.Parse (x.ToString ()));
            Console.WriteLine ("Soma dos numeros = " + digits.Sum());
            Console.ReadKey ();
        }
    }
}
```

Preveni seu desenvolvimento incluindo apenas a adaptação para o resultado final.

Comment: Eu sei mano, da pra fazer de várias formas, mas nem é sobre, somar os valores da string. A dúvida que surgiu pra mim, foi a questão de nao conseguir converter um índice de uma string para um inteiro. Eu quero saber só isso, como converter, por exemplo a string numero = 2345, numero[0] = 2, e pegar esse numero [0] e converter para inteiro, que eu não sei como, estou procurando ate agora. se eu converter usando Convert.ToInt32(numero[0]), nesse caso aí, era pra dar 2, mas da 50.

Comment: Na verdade o índice em si já está separado e é um inteiro. A conversão já está acontecendo no Lambda. O objeto "digits" é uma lista de inteiros. No seu exemplo 2345 o objeto está 2,3,4,5 (lista de inteiros).